# overwrite a txt file every hour instead of append using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I have a monitoring code from shodan https://help.shodan.io/guides/how-to-monitor-network

the script is continuously running and print the finding in CLI.
I extracted the data that I needed in this format `data=(f"{ip}:{port}")`
After appending the new finding to a txt file called ips.txt, I want every duration of time e.x: 2 hours, to overwrite the whole ips in the txt and start again write to the txt file.

As I wants to make some bash operations on the result in this duration and then another operations on the newly added data

**To Sum up:**
I want to delete all the data in the txt file after 2 hours and start appending again.

I wrote this time code but it did not work.

```
import subprocess
import time
import shlex
import json
from shodan import Shodan
from shodan.helpers import get_ip
from shodan.cli.helpers import get_api_key
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
file_path = 'ips.txt'

duration = 900
start_time = time.time()
# Setup the Shodan API connection
api = Shodan(get_api_key())
for banner in api.stream.alert():
        if 'port' in banner:
                        port=(banner['port'])
        ip = get_ip(banner)
                
        data=(f"{ip}:{port}")
while time.time() - start_time < duration:   
        with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
                file.write(data+'\n')
        time.sleep(5)
open(file_path, 'w').close()
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write('')
```

Comment: Have you considered `logrotate`?  Have you considered storing your lines in a small Redis instance with a TTL (*"Time To Live"*) that will expire them automagically or in a fixed length list where old entries get *"pushed off the end"* as new ones are added. They will still be available to other programs and utilities including `bash`, Python, C, Perl, Java and in fact they'll be readily available across a network which is potentially better than your text file. Or maybe a Python *"Multiprocessing  Manager"* list that other Python processes could connect to in order to access the readings?

Comment: Or maybe a maximum length Python list in your current program and adding a second thread that supports connections from clients to query the list contents.

Comment: can you elaborate more how can I use it, I will be more than happy if you elaborate the code.

Comment: It would depend on quite a few things... like how big each piece of data is, how often that data arrives, how long you need to keep it, what language the clients are, how often and in what way they use the data, where they are on the network and so on. Try running up a Redis instance (use docker if you don't want to do a full installation) and try some LPUSH and LTRIM operations just using the shell and maybe remotely by adding the IP address of your server. Then the Python is just the same really.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much cleaner with a Context Manager. This technique also obviates the need for continually opening and closing the output file.

```
from time import time
from shodan import Shodan
from shodan.helpers import get_ip
from shodan.cli.helpers import get_api_key


class IPSWriter:
    def __init__(self, filename, interval=7200):
        self._filename = filename
        self._interval = interval
        self._last_write = float("-inf")
        self._fd = None

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        if self._fd:
            self._fd.close()

    @property
    def fd(self):
        if self._fd is None:
            self._fd = open(self._filename, "w+")
        return self._fd

    def write(self, text):
        if (time() - self._interval) >= self._last_write:
            self.fd.seek(0)
            self.fd.truncate()
        self.fd.write(text)
        self.fd.flush()
        self._last_write = time()


file_path = "ips.txt"

api = Shodan(get_api_key())

with IPSWriter(file_path) as writer:
    try:
        for banner in api.stream.alert():
            port = banner.get("port")
            ip = get_ip(banner)
            data = f"{ip}:{port}\n"
            writer.write(data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # break loop with Ctrl-C
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still continue writing the new output after the time ends as I want after the time ends, to clear all the data in the txt file and start again from zero

Comment: @ELMO When you write to the file (using the class's *write()* function) after the interval has elapsed, the file is truncated and writing starts over

Comment: Somehow it does not work and it continue writing to the file without deleting the old data after the time ends